# Submitted app to itunes but still ask me to upload build?

Tags: ios, build, app-store-connect, itunes

I have submitted in three different ways app to itunes (xcode, app loader, and buddybuild ci) and still don't see build in Build section in itunes. Also I have noticed that when I try to upload the build with the same build number and version I get an error that build with this version and build number already exists. Should I just be patient and wait that apple complete some process over my build? - already takes more than hour

Comment: Every time you upload you need to increase your Build number, but it should give you an error when you try to upload if you didn't and not do the upload

Comment: That is fine, but I can't see build in itunes connect

Comment: Set it in Xcode - Click on Project, General, then Identity -> Build

Comment: We probably misunderstood,  I can build and upload to app store, but nothing presented in itunes connect

Comment: weird never had that happen...

Comment: Got an email with info.plist error, but after 2 days, probably something weird with apple